# Posting a file using $http service of AngularJs to ASP.NET MVC controller shows- "$digest already in progress." - in console

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post an excel file using AngularJS $http post and getting the following error in console - "$digest already in progress".

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
at beginPhase (http://localhost:19394/Scripts/angular.js:16200:9)
at Scope.prototype.$apply  (http://localhost:19394/Scripts/angular.js:15944:11)
at Anonymous function   (http://localhost:19394/app/core/core.directives.js:50:21)
at jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost:19394/Scripts/jquery-  2.1.4.js:4434:6)
at elemData.handle (http://localhost:19394/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js:4120:5)
```

My script follows,

```
      var fdata = new FormData();
      fdata.append('file', file);

        $http({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            data: fdata,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined, 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        });
```

My controller action follows,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAccounts(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

     }
```

By using the above code i'm able to upload the file, but after waiting some time (say 2-3 minutes the upload will not work).After every successful upload we can see the above console error. The Success and error events are getting triggered but the complete event is not getting triggered.

Any body please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling `$scope.$apply` anywhere?

Comment: @Grant: Yes, The script of Parent view has $scope.$apply. Even after commenting that line too the same error persists. But after commenting the post method the error is gone.

Comment: Alright, take a look at the answer i've added below and attempt to make it apply for you

Answer (score 0):

Generally the best way to fix a digest already in progress error is to use the `$timeout` function provided by AngularJS, This is what the AngularJS staff recommend, the reason this works is because the AngularJS `$timeout` function also runs whatever is inside of it on the next digest, even if a time isn't passed to the `$timeout`, isolate the area where your program is falling over. This is generally an `$apply` or something similar.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.someData = someData; //Whatever needs to happen next in here
}, 0);
```

The [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$digest) are pretty spot on with their common causes